The Windows Subsystem for Linux optional component is not enabled. エラーとなります。
Windows11 homeです。
以下のようにwslのインストールをしましたが、Ubuntuが起動しません。
どのような原因がありますでしょうか？
PS C:\Windows\system32> wsl --install
Ubuntu は既にインストールされています。
Ubuntu を起動しています...
The Windows Subsystem for Linux optional component is not enabled. Please enable it and try again.
See https://aka.ms/wslinstall for details.
Press any key to continue...
この操作を正しく終了しました。

PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux

FeatureName      : Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux
DisplayName      : Linux 用 Windows サブシステム
Description      : ネイティブなユーザー モードの Linux シェルおよびツールを Windows で実行するためのサービスと環境を提
                   供します。
RestartRequired  : Possible
State            : Enabled

※以下のようにWindowsの機能の有効化は完了しています。



また、以下Ubuntuのサイトからインストールし、Ubuntuアプリ(24.04LTS)を開いた結果もエラーになります。
Error: 0x8007019e Linux ? Windows ??????????????????
サイトURL：https://jp.ubuntu.com/download

これは参考になるでしょうか？ https://1nux.com/archives/280 。
Error: 0x8007019e Linux をGoogleで検索したら見付かりました。

「機能の有効化または無効化」を変更した後、Windows 自体の再起動は試しましたか？

@atsushi
そちら手順を試した結果、エラーが変わらずでした。

@cubick
再起動しましたが、やはり同様にエラーが発生してしまいます。
